# Date Range in PL/SQL (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I have table with a Date column called `myDate`, with values like `2009-08-25 09:00:09.0`.

I want to select all rows for *Aug 25*, from *12:00:01 AM* until *11:59:59 PM* and NOTHING for *Aug 26*. Is it sufficient to simply use the condition:

```
where myDate between Date '2009-08-25' and Date '2009-08-26'
```

And I want to select all rows BEFORE *Aug 25*, not including Aug 25. Can I do:

```
where myDate < Date '2009-08-25'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you want data for the full day 25 and excluding all the 26, you need to remove the first second of the 26:

```
where myDate >= Date '2009-08-25' and myDate < Date '2009-08-26'
```

or

```
where myDate between Date '2009-08-25' and Date '2009-08-26' - interval '1' second
```

**Update** -- A little precision: In Oracle the `DATE` datatype is used both for 'Date' types with or without time. If you're dealing with dates without time, it is usually stored with a 00:00 time segment, meaning midnight. Because of this, the first between (`my_date between '2009-08-25' and '2009-08-26'`) will potentially select two full days.

By removing the first second of the 26, you ensure that you won't inadvertently select rows from the 26.

Comment: What do you mean by Beginning of 26. If you don't include - 1/24/60/60
 in your second query, what problem may it have?

Comment: the 26 starts at 00:00, so if you want to exclude ALL the 26, you have to explicitly remove that second

Comment: Yes, it includes ONLY 8-26 12:00:00 AM. Not a minute after. The chances of a row happening exactly on midnight is low, so that's ok?

Comment: +1 and you might want to consider the more verbose interval '1' second notation, instead of 1/24/60/60.

Comment: @Saobi: I updated my answer: sometimes dates are stored without the time information (because it is irrelevant or unknown), in that case they are stored with a '12:00:00 AM' time segment. This is why it is safer to remove that first second

Comment: Wait, if the dates are stored without time (12:00:00 AM), then

where myDate between Date '2009-08-25' and Date '2009-08-26' 

will not include the 08-26 , right?

Comment: @Saobi: if the dates are stored without time, your between will select both the 08-25 and the 08-26

Comment: What's the query to check if any dates contains midnight?

Comment: If you want to check if the time component of a date contains midnight, you can search with this: "WHERE trunc(mydate) = mydate", you could also check that the time is 00: "WHERE to_char(mydate, 'hh24miss') = '000000'"

Answer (score 2):

To get everything between Aug 25, at 12:00:01 AM until 11:59:59 PM, inclusive, try this:

```
  Where myDate Between to_Date('yyyymmddhh24miss', '20090825000001') 
                  And  to_Date('yyyymmddhh24miss', '20090825235959')
```

(Why are you excluding midnight on the 25th ??  That first second (00:00:00) is part of the 25th as well... )

To get everything before Aug 25, try this:

```
Where myDate < to_Date('yyyymmdd', '20090825')
```

Answer (score 0):

This trunc the year but you get my gist:

```
SELECT (select trunc(sysdate - (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
                                       add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'), -24)
                                  FROM DUAL))from DUAL)+ (ROWNUM - 1) effective_date
                                  FROM DUAL
                                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'), -24)
                                  FROM DUAL);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT   *
FROM   TABLE
 WHERE   myDate BETWEEN myDate  ('08/25/2009', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                         AND  myDate  ('08/26/2009', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: He forgot TO_DATE before brackets